# Admob Banner Ads are not working properly in Unity3D

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, admob

I integrate **Ad-mob banner ads** in my Unity game project **android** build

But Sometimes the ad is showing but most of time it's not

showing percentage will be just just **4% out of 100%**

I don't know why this happening

I got this following code from [developers.google](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/banner) and i am able to show ads but it does not show the banner app on every startup frankly speaking it only shows ads in first or 2nd startup after build and not anymore.

I try to find solutions but looks like all solutions are same.

So, I am Stuck in here

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using GoogleMobileAds;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using UnityEngine;

public class BannerAd : MonoBehaviour
{

    private BannerView bannerView;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        string appID = "ca-app-pub-id"; // this is appId

        MobileAds.Initialize (appID);

        string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-adUnitId"; // adUnitID

        this.showBannerAd (adUnitId);
    }

    private void showBannerAd (string adUnitId)
    {



        //Create a custom ad size at the bottom of the screen

        AdSize adSize = new AdSize (250, 50);
        bannerView = new BannerView (adUnitId, adSize, AdPosition.Bottom);

        // Create an empty ad request.
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder ().Build ();

        // Load the banner with the request.
        bannerView.LoadAd (request);

        StartCoroutine(bannerAdTime());
    }

    IEnumerator bannerAdTime ()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (300f);

        RequestNewAd();
    }

    private void RequestNewAd ()
    {
        // Create an empty ad request.
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder ().Build ();

        // Load the banner with the request.
        bannerView.LoadAd (request);

        StartCoroutine(bannerAdTime());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try to use test ads and see if the problem persists?
It could tell us if the problem is in admob fill, or your code.

Comment: Ok, i will try that and let you know

Comment: thanks buddy, it works , sorry for late reply @Yakirbu

Comment: actually the problem is with my Emulator, when I using My Phone this works out Fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

The problem was with my **Emulator**

With The **Real Device** it work fine

and there's no need to use the co-routine

the following codes will be enough to show the BannderAds

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using GoogleMobileAds;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using UnityEngine;

public class BannerAd : MonoBehaviour
{

    private BannerView bannerView;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        string appID = "ca-app-pub-id"; // this is appId

        MobileAds.Initialize (appID);

        string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-adUnitId"; // adUnitID

        this.showBannerAd (adUnitId);
    }

    private void showBannerAd (string adUnitId)
    {

        //Create a custom ad size at the bottom of the screen

        AdSize adSize = new AdSize (250, 50);
        bannerView = new BannerView (adUnitId, adSize, AdPosition.Bottom);

        // Create an empty ad request.
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder ().Build ();

        // Load the banner with the request.
        bannerView.LoadAd (request);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

1.Check you have install plugin as document https://github.com/unity-plugins/Unity-Admob

2.Edit AndroidManifest.xml and config Admob APP ID
This configuration is reqired by admob from version 17.0,APP will crash if not config .Add a meta-data tag in application and set value to your admob appid

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="your admob app id"/>
```

Sample code

```
    <application  android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" 
   android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" 
   android:label="@string/app_name" >
           <activity
        android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>
  </application>
```

3.Init Admob Unity Plugin
Create A C# script ,drag the script to a object on scene , add the follow code in the script file

```
using admob;
Admob.Instance().initSDK("admob appid", new AdProperties());//admob id with format ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713
//Admob.Instance().initAdmob("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716", new AdProperties());
```

4.Add Admob Banner in Unity App

```
Admob.Instance().showBannerRelative("your admob banner unit id",AdSize.BANNER, AdPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER, 0);
```